# AngluarJS: Error: $injector:strictdi Explicit annotation required

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I am encountering an issue while running an AngluarJS based application:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myServer2App due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myServer2App.account due to:
[$injector:strictdi] routes is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode
```

As described in the documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/strictdi), it seems that something missing in injection annotations.

Looking at the error message, I tracked back the issue until **account.routes.js**:

The app.js:
[image]

The app/account/index.js
[image]

And finally the app/account/account.routes.js file:

```
'use strict';

export default function routes($stateProvider) {
  'ngInject';

  $stateProvider.state('login', {
          url: '/auth/smAuth',
          params: {
             target: false
           },
          controller: function ($location, $stateParams) {
            'ngInject';
            var target = '/auth/smAuth';
            if ($stateParams.target) target = target + '?target=' + encodeURIComponent($stateParams.target);
            // $location.path(target);
            window.location=target;
          }
        })
      .state('fallbackLogin', {
        url: '/login',
        template: require('./login/login.html'),
        controller: 'LoginController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
      })
      .state('logout', {
      url: '/logout?referrer',
      referrer: 'main',
      template: '',
      controller($state, Auth) {
        'ngInject';

        var referrer = $state.params.referrer || $state.current.referrer || 'main';
        Auth.logout();
        $state.go(referrer);
      }
    })
    .state('signup', {
      url: '/signup',
      template: require('./signup/signup.html'),
      controller: 'SignupController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      authenticate: 'admin'
    })
    .state('settings', {
      url: '/settings',
      template: require('./settings/settings.html'),
      controller: 'SettingsController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      authenticate: true
    });
}
```

Since in quite new in AngluarJS and the project is not mine, I am stuck to find a solution for this issue. Has someone any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: controller($state, Auth) { --> controller: function($state, Auth) { ?

Comment: Great, thank you! Another problema I found is that I run the App from the browser thorough port 3000 instead of 9000. Now, using 9000, works fine.